# Unable to create an apk file app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

Tags: android, flutter, apk

**Can you help me correct this error? I can't generate an apk, although the project worked very well before.** I am using the latest version android studio Giraffe

```
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:78:54: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
      image_provider.CachedNetworkImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) {
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:99:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:78:54: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
      image_provider.CachedNetworkImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) {
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:99:5: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:25:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.2.3/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:25:5: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:29:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:29:5: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_image.dart:32:48: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(BlurHashImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_image.dart:32:48: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(BlurHashImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_widget.dart:218:42: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(UiImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_widget.dart:218:42: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(UiImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I am on flutter android studio latest version giraffe

Comment: Provide your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  get: ^4.6.5
  intl: ^0.18.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.20
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.3.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0

Comment: country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  phone_number: ^1.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.7
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.5+3
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.3.7
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.9.3+4
  shimmer_animation: ^2.1.0+1
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.3
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.1
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  file_picker: ^5.2.6
  timelines: ^0.1.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.3
  universal_html: ^2.2.1
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3
  timeago: ^3.4.0
  pdf: ^3.10.1
  fwfh_selectable_text: ^0.8.3+1
  diffutil_dart: ^3.0.0
  flutter_downloader: ^1.10.2
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  printing: ^5.11.0
  audioplayers: ^3.0.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  expandable_bottom_sheet: ^1.1.1+1
  share_plus: ^6.3.1
  rect_getter: ^1.1.0
  scroll_to_index: ^3.0.1
  http_parser: ^4.0.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  path: ^1.8.2
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^21.1.39

Comment: dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

Comment: You should [edit] your post and put the contents of `pubspec.yaml` in the post, not in the comments

Answer (score 1):

I changed my `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip` from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip` and it worked.